# Runtime error in NVIDA video codec sample project

Tags: nvidia, nvenc

I tested the nv codec SDK project "NvDecodeD3D11" from the Video_Codec_SDK_8.0.14. When I compile it, the error happens at cuvidCtxLockCreate(&g_CtxLock, g_oContext);

It said the access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000 meaning that the g_CtxLock is NULL. How can I solve it?

You may download the source code from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/designworks/video_codec_sdk/downloads/v8.0

I used VS 2013 to compile and configure it in x64 platform.

```
   void initCudaVideo()
    {
        // bind the context lock to the CUDA context
        CUresult result = cuvidCtxLockCreate(&g_CtxLock, g_oContext);
        CUVIDEOFORMATEX oFormatEx;
        memset(&oFormatEx, 0, sizeof(CUVIDEOFORMATEX));
        oFormatEx.format = g_stFormat;

        if (result != CUDA_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cuvidCtxLockCreate failed: %d\n", result);
            assert(0);
        }

        CUVIDEOFORMAT videoFormat = g_pVideoSource->format();
        CUVIDDECODECAPS videoDecodeCaps = {};
        videoDecodeCaps.eCodecType = videoFormat.codec;
        videoDecodeCaps.eChromaFormat = videoFormat.chroma_format;
        videoDecodeCaps.nBitDepthMinus8 = videoFormat.bit_depth_luma_minus8;
        if (cuvidGetDecoderCaps(&videoDecodeCaps) != CUDA_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cuvidGetDecoderCaps failed: %d\n", result);
            return;
        }
        if (!videoDecodeCaps.bIsSupported) {
            printf("Error: This video format isn't supported on the selected GPU.");
            exit(1);;
        }
        // If XxY is max supported resolution for a codec on a GPU and YxX resolution
        // is also supported then Max Supported width is Max(X, Y) and Max supported height is Max(X, Y)
        // But Max supported MBCount is XxY / 256.
        // E.g. 4096x2304 is max supported resolution and 2304x4096 is also supported then
        // Max Width = 4096, Max Height = 4096, But Max supported MB Count = 4096*2304 / 256 = 36864
        printf("This video format is supported on the selected GPU. \n"
               "    Min resolution supported : %dx%d\n"
               "    Max width supported      : %d\n"
               "    Max height supported     : %d\n"
               "    Max macroblocks supported: %d\n", videoDecodeCaps.nMinWidth, videoDecodeCaps.nMinHeight, 
               videoDecodeCaps.nMaxWidth, videoDecodeCaps.nMaxHeight, videoDecodeCaps.nMaxMBCount);

        std::unique_ptr<VideoDecoder> apVideoDecoder(new VideoDecoder(g_pVideoSource->format(), g_oContext, g_eVideoCreateFlags, g_CtxLock));
        std::unique_ptr<VideoParser> apVideoParser(new VideoParser(apVideoDecoder.get(), g_pFrameQueue, &oFormatEx));
        g_pVideoSource->setParser(*apVideoParser.get());

        g_pVideoParser  = apVideoParser.release();
        g_pVideoDecoder = apVideoDecoder.release();

        // Create a Stream ID for handling Readback
        if (g_bReadback)
        {
            checkCudaErrors(cuStreamCreate(&g_ReadbackSID, 0));
            checkCudaErrors(cuStreamCreate(&g_KernelSID,   0));
            printf("> initCudaVideo()\n");
            printf("  CUDA Streams (%s) <g_ReadbackSID = %p>\n", ((g_ReadbackSID == 0) ? "Disabled" : "Enabled"), g_ReadbackSID);
            printf("  CUDA Streams (%s) <g_KernelSID   = %p>\n", ((g_KernelSID   == 0) ? "Disabled" : "Enabled"), g_KernelSID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not a cuda sample project.  That is a nv codec SDK sample project.   The cuda samples are listed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html).  On SO, when asking a question that is "why isn't this working?" you are supposed to provide a [mcve]

Comment: This sample is related to Video Decoder API, which is based also on CUDA.Are you sure you have created a valid CUDA device and context?

Comment: At last, I found my displayboard does not support NVCODEC which is too old.